# Local time display with Global time in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im storing time in DATETIME format and I need to display the time in local zone related time, I have no idea how to achieve in PHP, any ideas?

Comment: to display/format locat time see [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

List of time zones is available here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: When you use this method, any DATETIME values you have will be converted to the new time zone.